# What database permissions to grant for Postfix using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postfix

I'm trying to set up a Postfix mail server using MySQL for the mapping tables. As it's bad practice to simply grant all permissions unless they're needed, I want to grant only the minimal permissions required to make Postfix work.

Unfortunately, even the [Postfix MySQL Howto](http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html) doesn't seem to want to give up this info, and my Google-fu is inconclusive, mainly because there are a *lot* of pages that talk about Postfix and MySQL before going on to talk about restricting file permissions for the config :)

Can I get away with just SELECT, or does Postfix need more than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the SELECT permission for Postfix as it only runs SELECT queries on those tables.

In this kind of setup you are also likely to have some admin panel which will have to write to those tables. So it's best to setup a read only user for Postfix and a separate read/write user for the admin panel.

Comment: Thanks — I'm doing the writes over SSH from a desktop client rather than installing a web control panel, so that side's already OK :)